# Two conducting rods move on top of two conductors in a non-uniform magnetic field. Problem regarding the EMF of the circuit formed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-induction

An infinite length conductor (1) with electric current I creates a magnetic field $B=\frac{μ_0I}{2πr}$, where r is the distance from the conductor. Two parallel long wires, (2) and (3) (in the direction of EH and ZΘ as shown below) are perpendicular to conductor (1) and in the same plane. On top of them, the rods EZ and ΗΘ slide with speeds $v_1$ and $v_2$ (with $v_1<v_2$) as shown below. At some point, when the distance between the two rods is a, we notice that there isn't any induced current in the circuit ZEHΘΖ. Find the distance of EZ from the conductor (1) at that point in time.

[image]

That's the entire exercise, no initial conditions are provided so I assume that the initial distance of EZ and (1) is $c_0$, the initial distance between EZ and HΘ is $d_0$ and the length of each rod is L. I'm also assuming the velocities are constant, therefore we have $c(t)=c_0+v_1t$ and $d(t)=d_0+(v_2-v_1)t$.

I'm having some trouble with the solution, so here's what I've though so far:

Since the magnetic field, velocity and orientation of the rods are always perpendicular to each other, the inducted EMF can be calculated using $ε=BvL$ (or is this wrong?). Obviously, the wires (2) and (3) have no inducted EMF.

We calculate the inducted EMFs for each of the rods EZ and HΘ, $ε_1$ and $ε_2$ respectively as:

$ε_1=\frac{μ_0Iv_1L}{2πc(t)}$ and $ε_2=\frac{μ_0Iv_2L}{2π[c(t)+d(t)]}$

Both EMFs are directer towards the top of the circuit loop so the total EMF of the circuit should be

$ε=ε_1-ε_2=\frac{μ_0Iv_1L}{2πc(t)}-\frac{μ_0Iv_2L}{2π[c(t)+d(t)]}$

Doing the math we get that $ε=\frac{μ_0IL}{2π}\frac{c(t)(v_2-v_1)+v_1d(t)}{c(t)[c(t)+d(t)]}$

Lets assume that for some moment in time, $t_0$, the distance between the two rods is a, which means that $d(t_0)=a$. At that moment, there is no induced current in the circuit, which means that $ε=0$. Using that, we can find the time $t_0$:

$ε=0\Rightarrow c(t)(v_2-v_1)+v_1d(t)=0\Rightarrow (c_0+v_1t)(v_2-v_1)=v_1[d_0+(v_2-v_1)t]\Rightarrow c_0(v_2-v_1)+v_1t(v_2-v_1)=v_1d_0+v_1t(v_2-v_1)\Rightarrow c_0(v_2-v_1)=v_1d_0$

As you can see, time is completely thrown out and we get a "solution" that gives a relationship between the constants we assumed at the beginning of the problem, which seems incorrect, because that would imply that for some sets of constants that fulfill this equation, the EMF would be constantly 0 while the rods are moving. Not to mention that this definitely isn't what the exercise implies...

I also tried solving it using Faraday's Law of induction but I got the same result. Where is my mistake? Is there a possibility that the exercise is incorrect?

Comment: I found the same as you. The condition for zero current is $$\frac{v_2}{v_1}=\frac{\ell_2}{\ell_1}$$ in which $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ are the initial distances of the rods from the long wire. As you say, this is time-independent.

Comment: If it's correct then the exercise's questions are wrong, because the distance "a" is ANY distance and "Find the distance of EZ from the conductor (1) at that point in time" doesn't even apply because it can be ANY point in time, which means that there's an infinite amount of different distances that can be used...

Comment: That's what I thought. Maybe we're both making the same mistake, but I'd be surprised. Perhaps someone else will comment.

Comment: My working, for what its worth: for zero current $$\frac{\mu_0 I v_1L}{2\pi (\ell_1 + v_1 t)} =\frac{\mu_0 I v_2 L}{2\pi (\ell_2 + v_2 t)},$$ whence $$\frac{v_1}{\ell_1 + v_1 t} =\frac{v_2 }{\ell_2 + v_2 t}$$ in which $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ are the distances of the rod from the wire at time $t=0$.